# Wordpad does not show image properly

Tags: image-editing, wordpad

I have an .rtf file and there is an image in it. When I open that with MSWord it show image properly, but with WordPad it show a yellow rectangle instead. What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find that WordPad probably just does not support that feature of `.rft` files. It's designed as a very basic word processing tool without many additional features.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad

> WordPad natively supports the Rich Text Format, though it does not support all the features defined in the RTF/Word 2007 specification.